# New Column gives insert error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table, which the website has been running inserts against, no problem. Then I added one column (which allows nulls), and I get the specified error. I have edited the insert to include the new column, but I get the same error. I have scripted the table, recreated a copy of it (with copies of all the constraints, etc), and the insert runs fine (with or without the new column). Delete the new column (in the original table), I can make the insert run again. Here is the insert, which works on the copy of the table, but not the table itself. Googling just gives example of people having problems with inserts which aren't valid, but mine is! Please can someone help?

```html
insert into tbleventstest
(
      [text]
      ,[SeriesId]
      ,[eventStart]
...truncated.
      ,[fba] --new column
)
values
(
      'flibble'  --[text]
      ,666411 --[SeriesId]
      ,'01-jan-2017 13:00' --[eventStart]
...truncated.
      ,null --[fba]
)
```

Comment: Please provide the Table definition as well

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved my own problem. In case it helps anyone else: The table in question had a trigger on it something like so...

insert tblEvents_copy 
    select * from  inserted i where etc....

(where tblevents_copy is obviously intended to be an identical table, added by someone else, which I'd forgotten existed).

So the error was caused by attempting to insert into tblevents_copy, rather than my initial insert. And the issue I would take is that the error message could have much clearer in explaining which insert into which table was failing. Would have saved me a lot of time.  Thanks to anyone who looked. Not sure why my question has a -4...